# auditquery hibernate envers with join

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have added `Hibernate envers` to one project, for saving and showing the auditions.
I used the following statement for query revisions showing audited records.

```
AuditQuery auditQuery = getAuditReader().createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Entity.class, false, true);
```

in this query, I want to join related entities, but i couldn't find any method in `AuditQuery` for join.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar situation. I had a parent object, which had children, and I needed to recreate the parent and all its children for a given point in time.

I had to do it manually. In my case I had an abstract DAO object that all my DAO's inherit, so this was easy to do. First I added a getRev method to my base DAO, that gets children objects for parent object. For example, lets say we had a Car parent object (that has Doors and Tires as children).

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseDAO<T extends IModel> implements BaseDAO<T> {
    @Autowired(required=true) protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public AbstractBaseDAO(Class<?> myClass) {
        this.typeParameterClass = (Class<T>)myClass;
    }

    // ... other generic DAO methods, including some CRUD methods

    public List<T> getRev(ICar car, Integer rev) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get( session );
        AuditQueryCreator queryCreator = reader.createQuery(); 
        AuditQuery query = queryCreator.forEntitiesAtRevision(typeParameterClass, rev);
        query.add(AuditEntity.property("car").eq(car));

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> result = query.getResultList();         

        return result;
    }
}
```

To add some context to how this base DAO is used, I create the object specific DAO's as such:

```
public class TireDAO extends AbstractBaseDAO<ITire> {
    public TireDAO() {
        super(Tire.class);
    }
}
public class DoorDAO extends AbstractBaseDAO<IDoor> {
    public DoorDAO() {
        super(Door.class);
    }
}
```

I override this for the parent's DAO, because in that case we want to get the parent object itself instead of getting children objects for that parent:

```
public class CarDAO extends AbstractBaseDAO<ICar> {
    public CarDAO() {
        super(Car.class);
    }

    @Override
    public ICar getRev(Integer id, Integer rev) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get( session );
        AuditQueryCreator queryCreator = reader.createQuery(); 
        AuditQuery query = queryCreator.forEntitiesAtRevision(typeParameterClass, rev);
        query.add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id));

        return (SecurityUser)query.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Now, in my service object which I use to get a Car for a specific revision, I add a method like this:

```
@Autowired(required=true) CarDAO carDao;
@Autowired(required=true) TireDAO tireDao;
@Autowired(required=true) DoorDAO doorDao;

@Transactional
public ICar getFullRevision(Integer id, Integer rev) throws Exception {
    ICar car = this.carDao.getRev(id, rev);

    Set<ITire> tires = new HashSet<ITire>(tireDAO.getRev(car, rev));
    car.setTires(tires);

    Set<IDoor> doors = new HashSet<IDoor>(doorDAO.getRev(car, rev));
    car.setDoors(doors);

    return car;
}
```

Comment: Oh, and please excuse the Spring @Autowired annotations. I left those in for clarity's sake.

Comment: thanks for your solution, i solved my problem with another similar solution
of course , your answer is better than my solution.
But i want to get the all revisions with one trip to database; and using the similar to JPQL queries, that can have filter.

Answer (score 1):

As the docs say, joins are not currently supported by audit queries.

Comment: The solution is to implement the feature in Hibernate :)

Comment: its very bad. i want this now. :(